# MiMa complains about loss of a synthetic method, even though I put the original line back in place

Tags: scala, binary-compatibility, migration-manager

I'm trying to understand the following message from Migration Manager:

```
Found 1 binary incompatibilities
================================
 * synthetic method
   de$sciss$lucre$synth$impl$NodeGraphImpl$$ugenGraphs()scala.concurrent.stm.Ref
   in class de.sciss.lucre.synth.impl.NodeGraphImpl does not have a
   correspondent in new version
```

The class `NodeGraphImpl` is a final class, and `ugenGraphs` was a `private val`. What I did is remove the following:

```
private val ugenGraphs = Ref(Map.empty[GraphEquality, SynthDef])
```

I understand that `private` is not `private[this]`, so theoretically an incompatibility could arise of the removal. Ok.

I try and keep that value in there. The error *still* does not go away. My theory is that the compiler might remove the method because it is never invoked? I try to create a dummy access to that value, e.g.

```
def foo(): Unit = ugenGraphs.apply()
```

*Still* the error doesn't go away. I also changed the version of my snapshot to make sure it's not a caching problem of MiMa. So why does it insist on the missing of that synthetic method?

[Here](https://github.com/Sciss/SoundProcesses/blob/484ad7735af06bd8e1f8bfacb6917b95e3b3bd1d/synth/src/main/scala/de/sciss/lucre/synth/impl/NodeGraphImpl.scala#L125) is the original code.

**Hypothesis**: The method MiMa complains about was generated because of the closure argument to `getOrElse` from where `ugenGraphs` is accessed. If that is the case, **is it still safe** to consider the new version binary compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the original `getSynthDef` method renamed to `geSynthDefOLD` makes MiMa happy again, so indeed the synthetic method must have been generated as a consequence of the body to `getSynthDef`.